# tweetinvi or tweetsharp inside proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, tweetsharp, tweetinvi

I am using tweetinvi in my program to search in Twitter but I am access to internet throw proxy. When I run a program inside proxy the tweetinvi face error.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the documentation to use proxies with Tweetinvi.

https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Configuration

```
// Simple proxy
TweetinviConfig.CurrentThreadSettings.ProxyURL = "http://228.23.13.21:4287";

// Proxy with password
TweetinviConfig.CurrentThreadSettings.ProxyURL = "http://username:password@228.23.13.21:4287";
```